# Return all tuple only from list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to return only tuple1,tuple2,tuple3 for the list

```
def list_read():
type12=[(u'War', u'Anime', u'Anime', u'Comedy'), (u'DVD', u'DVD', u'DVD', u'VHS'), (u'PG', u'R', u'PG', u'PG')]#...so on]
for each in type12:
    print(each)#my output is (u'War', u'Anime', u'Anime', u'Comedy')
               #(u'DVD', u'DVD', u'DVD', u'VHS')
               # (u'PG', u'R', u'PG', u'PG')
               #...........
return  (u'War', u'Anime', u'Anime', u'Comedy'),(u'DVD', u'DVD', u'DVD', u'VHS'),(u'PG', u'R', u'PG', u'PG')
#these format so that i will save to database
# ie Inserting_Data_base=INSERT INTO table_name(A,B,....) values (%s,%s,%s......)
```

Comment: What do you want as an output? `

Comment: It should return all tuple in single return  (u'War', u'Anime', u'Anime', u'Comedy'),(u'DVD', u'DVD', u'DVD', u'VHS'),(u'PG', u'R', u'PG', u'PG')

Answer (score 0):

```
for each in type[:3]:
```

Will iterate only through first 3 elements

As @OBP mentioned - you can just

```
return list[:3]
```

to return first 3 elements, if you don't need to modify them in your `for` loop

Comment: But when it is return list...then its overriding and giving late values only

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return the first 3 values:

```
return lst[:3]
```

By the way, using the reserved word 'type' as a variable name is wrong.

Comment: `type` is not one of the reserved words though: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords It might not be safe to use it as an argument to a function, but otherwise - there is no problem at all.